# React addEventListener in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I do the Keyboard Press Handle on React but in class component?
I research a lot but I always found it on function, not in class component.
Here is my code:

```
class Video extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', this.videoSeekN5);
        window.addEventListener('keypress', this.videoSeek5);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('keypress', this.videoSeekN5);
        window.removeEventListener('keypress', this.videoSeek5);
    }
    videoSeekN5(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            console.log('work')
            this.refs.videoRefer.currentTime -= 5;
        }
    }
    videoSeek5(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            console.log('work')
            this.refs.videoRefer.currentTime += 5;
        }
    }
```

Every time I press the left and right keys, it doesn't echo 'work' in the console, like it should be if it works.
I'm kinda used to JavaScript when I made my PHP site since 2018

Comment: Change `videoSeekN5(e) {}` to be `videoSeekN5 = (e) => {}` and same for `videoSeek5 `

Comment: You need to bind this for the functions in the constructor or declare them like `functionName = () => {}` instead of `videoSeek5(e) {}`